# Getting "b is undefined" in my .js file with LimeJS

Tags: google-closure, google-closure-library, limejs

I'm trying to use the javascript compiled file, but I get "b is undefined" since I launch the app with it.
I have really no idea where does it come from.

I removed et init again the sources from LimeJS, updated the dept. 
The problem still..

Any idea?

Comment: Lime JS uses the Closure Compiler, right? Can you enable the --debug option? Are any other scripts loading that might conflict?

Comment: Does your app work properly in debug? (i.e. with the non-closure-compiled code?)  "X is undefined" errors after compiling with Closure are usually because there's some custom object which Closure is not aware of accessing a member property via "dot notation" instead of "key notation". For example something like:  `code` myCustomObj.myCustomProperty `code`  instead of:  `code` myCustomObj['myCustomProperty'] `code`  A better solution (if this is your issue) than using "key notation" is to declare the property as part of a class or provide appropriate externs.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use goog.exportSymbol() on the methods you want to use when your code is compressed ? If not the compiler changes the function's names to compress them to optimize compression !